# ¿Cómo incluir el count en este caso?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Necesito contar la cantidad de registros del campo accommodation_id en la tabla bookings pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22) SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column
>   not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bookings.accommodation_id' in 'field
>   list' (SQL: select count(bookings.accommodation_id) as count from
>   `accommodations` where `accommodations`.`user_id` is null and `status`
>   in (PUBLISHED, DRAFT, PAUSED) group by `bookings`.`id`)

```
public function index()
{

    $id = Auth::id();
    $properties = Accommodation::with([ 'user' => function ($query) { $query->with('bookings'); } ]) 

                            ->where('accommodations.user_id', $id) 
                            ->whereIn('status', ['PUBLISHED', 'DRAFT', 'PAUSED'])
                            ->selectRaw('count(bookings.accommodation_id) as count')
                            ->groupBy('bookings.id')
                            ->get();

    return  view('admin/accommodations/index', compact('properties'));
}
```

Modelos:

```
class Accommodation extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function bookings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Booking::class);
    } 

}


class Booking extends Model
{

    public function accommodation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Accommodation::class);
    } 


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    } 


}
```

Comment: Agrega tus modelos para ver donde y como están declaradas cada una de las relaciones que involucras en tu consulta

Comment: Las agregué en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primer comentario.**

Si estás hablando de contar las veces que  `accomodation_id`  aparece en la tabla de  `bookings`  entonces no es una relación de uno a uno, sino de uno a muchos; por lo cual el método en la relación debe ser  `hasMany`  así:

```
public function accommodations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Accommodation::class);
}
```

**Segundo comentario.**

Si tratas de hacer dicho conteo entonces me parece que la forma de proceder debe ser:

- Invoca al modelo  `Booking`
- Pasa como segundo argumento la función anónima que ejecutará una serie de  `where`  por dentro

**Importante**

> Idealmente selecciona todas las columnas de  `Booking`  por las que deseas agrupar y estas mismas serán las que debas pasar al método  `groupBy`  ya que Laravel trae el modo estricto por default activado y agrupar por solo una columna cuando seguro recuperas mas tal vez te genere un error.

Propuesta:

```
$id = algo;
$data = Booking::query()
        ->select(['unaColumna', 'id', 'otraColumna'])
        ->with(['accomodations' => function($query) use($id){
        $query->select('accomodations.booking_id', 'otraColumna')
              ->where('accomodations.user_id', $id);
}])->whereIn('status', ['PUBLISHED', 'DRAFT', 'PAUSED'])
    ->selectRaw('count(bookings.accommodation_id) as count')
    ->groupBy('bookings.id')
    ->get();
```

Si acaso estás usando PHP 7.4 o superior tu consulta puede quedar así:

```
$data = Booking::query()
                ->select(['unaColumna', 'id', 'otraColumna'])
                ->with(["accomodations" => fn($query) => $query->select('accomodations.booking_id')->where("accomodations.user_id", $id)])
                ->whereIn('status', ['PUBLISHED', 'DRAFT', 'PAUSED'])
                ->selectRaw('count(bookings.accommodation_id) as count')
                ->groupBy('bookings.id')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Hola Aprendiz, conrespecto a las relaciones lo pensé de la siguiente manera: Un accommodation (Un alojamiento) puede tener varias reservaciones, y un Boooking (reservación) pertenece a un Accommodation (Un alojamiento). Tomando en cuenta tu propuesta la cambié hasMany y también invoqué el Modelo Booking, utilizando tu primer código me muestra un error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'accommodations.booking_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `accommodations` where `accommodations`.`booking_id` in (0) and `accommodations`.`user_id` is null)

Comment: eliminando la línea de código del whereIn me da el mismo error que me muestra el código inicial, por el que escribí acá: lluminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22)
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'accommodations.booking_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `accommodations` where `accommodations`.`booking_id` in (0) and `accommodations`.`user_id` is null)

Comment: Dame oportunidad y más tarde te contesto con algunas ediciones

Comment: Okey, gracias. Estaré atento.

Comment: Gracias, con las modificaciones lo logré... Ahora debo chequear las relaciones para poder obtener los datos que necesito de las tablas sin que me afecte a las demás relaciones que ya funcionan.